# If someone who owner of android library in jcenter delete the library, what happen? my android application which downloaded the library

Tags: android, gradle

I downloaded the android library by gradle, but If someone who owner of android library in jcenter delete the library, what happen? my android application which downloaded the library?

because, there is no library file in my android project even if I downloaded by gradle..

Answer (score 2):

When you're adding a library to your project, it gets *compiled* and sent out with your app (your apk). So, if someone deletes external dependencies, it won't have any* impact on your app which is already compiled, because the library will have already been compiled with your apk.

Now, going forward, if you open your project again in your IDE and you try to retrieve dependencies again, there will be a problem (because that dependency doesn't exist anymore) which will prevent your from *further* using this library, unless you've cloned it locally and added it into your project.

---

*Assuming it isn't a library which maybe has servers it connects to, if the servers go down then it will obviously also fail in your app, regardless

Comment: you're welcome,  i hope this answers what you were looking for, hopefully it makes sense